# Why is the output of the code 8,5,5 and not 8,8,5?

Tags: c, pointers, scope, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void f(int x, int* y, int **z)
{
    *z = malloc(sizeof(int));
    **z = 4;
    **z += 1;
    x += 2;
    *y += 3;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int *y = &x;
    int **z = &y;
    f(x, y, z);
    printf("%d, %d, %d", x, *y, **z);
    return 0;
}
```

So,here is my take on the problem-

first in the main z and y point to x which is 5.When function is called new variables x,y,z are created of their types and y,z in the function beginning eventually point to the x in the main.Now z is made to point to a int space in heap.Here the value of z pointing to the heap becomes 5.then x in the function becomes 7 and in the last line of function *y+=3 makes an increment to x value in main (making it 8).

now the flow of control returns to main

and x should be x in main that is 8 y should be 8 since it points to x in main. and z should be 5 since it points in the heap.

where did I go wrong?

Comment: Think about how `int **z = &y;` affects things. Where does `y` point after the function? https://godbolt.org/z/Gb61Pr86d

Comment: @RetiredNinja after seeing the addresses I think the malloc statement made original y point in the heap and *y+=3 just used the new y in the function to increment value of x;

Comment: After the function both `y` and `*z` point to the memory allocated in the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f`'s `z` points to `main`'s `y`, not `f`'s `y`. `main`'s `y` and `f`'s `y` are distinct variables, even if they have the same value for a time. Changing one doesn't change the other.

---

I'm going to illustrate what is happening as we step through the program line by line (more or less). But first, I'm going to rename `f`'s parameters to avoid confusion.

```c
void f(int a, int* b, int **c)
{
    *c = malloc(sizeof(int));
    **c = 4;
    **c += 1;
    a += 2;
    *b += 3;
}
```

1. After

   ```c
   int x = 5;
   int *y = &x;
   int **z = &y;
   ```

   we have

   ```
   int **z @ 3000     int *y @ 2000      int x @ 1000
   +-----------+      +-----------+      +-----------+
   | 2000   --------->| 1000   --------->|         5 |
   +-----------+      +-----------+      +-----------+
   ```

   (All addresses invented. The exact numbers are irrelevant.)
2. We call `f`. This copies `main`'s `x`, `y` and `z` into `f`'s `a`, `b` and `c`.

   ```
   int **z @ 3000     int *y @ 2000      int x @ 1000
   +-----------+      +-----------+      +-----------+
   | 2000   ------+-->| 1000   ------+-->|         5 |
   +-----------+  |   +-----------+  |   +-----------+
        ||        |        ||        |        ||
        ||        |        ||        |        ||
       copy       |       copy       |       copy
        ||        |        ||        |        ||
        VV        |        VV        |        VV
   int **c @ 6000 |   int *b @ 5000  |   int a @ 4000
   +-----------+  |   +-----------+  |   +-----------+
   | 2000   ------+   | 1000   ------+   |         5 |
   +-----------+      +-----------+      +-----------+
   ```
3. After

   ```c
   *c = malloc(sizeof(int));
   ```

   we have

   ```
                                         int @ 7000
                                         +-----------+
                                    +--->| ????????? |
                                    |    +-----------+
                                    |
   int **z @ 3000     int *y @ 2000 |    int x @ 1000
   +-----------+      +-----------+ |    +-----------+
   | 2000   ------+-->| 7000   -----+ +->|         5 |
   +-----------+  |   +-----------+   |  +-----------+
                  |                   |
   int **c @ 6000 |   int *b @ 5000   |  int a @ 4000
   +-----------+  |   +-----------+   |  +-----------+
   | 2000   ------+   | 1000   -------+  |         5 |
   +-----------+      +-----------+      +-----------+
   ```

   Remember that `c` points to `main`'s `y`.
4. After

   ```c
   **c = 4;
   **c += 1;
   a += 2;
   *b += 3;
   ```

   we have

   ```
                                         int @ 7000
                                         +-----------+
                                    +--->|         5 | (4+1)
                                    |    +-----------+
                                    |
   int **z @ 3000     int *y @ 2000 |    int x @ 1000
   +-----------+      +-----------+ |    +-----------+
   | 2000   ------+-->| 7000   -----+ +->|         8 | (5+3)
   +-----------+  |   +-----------+   |  +-----------+
                  |                   |
   int **c @ 6000 |   int *b @ 5000   |  int a @ 4000
   +-----------+  |   +-----------+   |  +-----------+
   | 2000   ------+   | 1000   -------+  |         7 | (5+2)
   +-----------+      +-----------+      +-----------+
   ```
5. Then, back in `main`, we print `x`, `*y` (the anon block),  and `**z` (again, the anon block via `*y`).

Comment: (lol! I hadn't noticed that the other answer had also renamed the parameters to `a`, `b` and `c`!)

Comment: Great minds think alike. Or is it "small minds seldom differ"?

Comment: @Chris https://www.youtube.com/shorts/s2a-DsX9Ezg

Answer (score 3):

First off, the `x += 2` in `f` means absolutely nothing because of pass-by-value semantics and it's never used again, so let's get rid of it.

```
void f(int x, int* y, int **z)
{
    *z = malloc(sizeof(int));
    **z = 4;
    **z += 1;
    *y += 3;
}
```

`z` is a pointer to `y`. When we dereference it and assign we're assigning to `y` *in `main`*. *That* `y` now points to some block of memory the right size for an `int`. The `y` that's our function argument is unchanged by this.

We now assign `4` to that chunk of memory, and then we increment it by `1`. The `y` in `main` is now `5`.

The `y` function argument still points to `x` in `main`, so when we dereference it and add `3`, it's now `8`.

The `z` in `main` still points to `y`, so that's `5` as well.

Thus `8, 5, 5` is printed.

Pass-by-value semantics in C are the real kicker here. I wonder if this would be easier to understand if we were looking at:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void f(int a, int* b, int **c)
{
    *c = malloc(sizeof(int));
    **c = 4;
    **c += 1;
    a += 2;
    *b += 3;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int *y = &x;
    int **z = &y;
    f(x, y, z);
    printf("%d, %d, %d", x, *y, **z);
    return 0;
}
```